# Need help getting the correct time for a time series in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have a dataset that I am passing through a time series. While the time series is working, I can not figure out how to add dates to my graph. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Plasterdo<- ts(PlasterDO)
plot.ts(Plasterdo)
```

Data:

[image: Data Set]

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and not as images. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If I get you correct, the index is being plotted on the x-axis, using the following example:

```
mat = cbind(S1=runif(5),S2=rnorm(5))
rownames(mat)=c("2019-01-07", "2019-01-20", 
"2019-02-18", "2019-02-17", "2019-03-28")

plot(ts(mat))
```

[[image: enter image description here]]

To get dates, you use zoo and as.Date() :

```
plot(zoo(mat,as.Date(rownames(mat))))
```

[image]